# Where goes the undeclared variables in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I try to understand what (and how) does some old VBA code.

I have a `Sub`, and I have a variable that is not declared in that *Sub*.

The `Option Explicit` is set to `False`.

Should I consider that variable a global one? Didn't found that info in the VBA docs...

```
Sub test1()
    x = "test one"
End Sub

Sub test2()
    x = "test2"
    Call test1
    MsgBox (">'" + x + "'<")
End Sub
```

[image]

there is no way to navigate to the definition of an undeclared variable
[image]

Comment: I can't think of any valid reason that someone is aware about `Option Explicit` and decide not to use it.

Comment: @FunThomas When I try to understand what does the old VBA code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, undeclared variables are created local to the method/subroutine. It will be deallocated when you exit the routine.  If you reference the same variable name in another routine, it will just create another uninitialized local variable.

Comment: can I found that somewhere in the "official" doc?

Comment: @serge Regarding scope and visibility: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-scope-and-visibility And regarding "lifetime": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-the-lifetime-of-variables

Comment: @JNevill the docs says that "You determine the scope of a variable when you declare it" however nothing is said when if you don't declare it... if I read the other developer's code, is hard to understand where the implicit variable was declared

Comment: @serge The [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-scope-and-visibility) says that "*variables defined within a procedure are procedure-local*".  Undeclared variables are implicitly defined when you try to use them, which means that implicit definition always happens within a procedure in VBA (there's no other way to "use" a variable).

Comment: @RBarryYoung "when you try to use them"... If I am not the author of the code, is hard to understand where is the first "try" to use them... The Excel VBA can't navigate to definition, so hard to understand if is local, module or global variable

Comment: @serge that is a fair statement "If you aren't the author of the code". There may be no clear way to understand if `x` is global without going and searching out the explicit definition of `x` outside of any procedure. But... also to be fair, VBA is a pretty not-great language and VBE is a pretty not-great IDE. If you are going to implement a feature in excel that is sufficiently complex or with a team of developers something like a C# add-on is probably a cleaner way to go.

Comment: @serge As I noted above, there's no other way to use a variable except in executable code.  In VBA executable code *only* occurs and is executed within procedures.  All code outside of procedures is declarative (and thus, non-executable) code. I grant you that the doc doesn't cover this very well and a lot of it is implication, but that's the way it is.  If you asked Microsoft, they would say to just use `Option Explicit` and then you wouldn't have any doubts.

Comment: @RBarryYoung ah, thanks, I got the point, undeclared variables may occur only inside a procedure, and never at the module or global level

Comment: Also, inside VBE (the IDE for VBA) you should be able to use *Shift-F2* to go to the definition of any variable (available from the popup menu also).  For undeclared variables it will either goto the first use or just not go anywhere (I'm not sure because I always use Option Explicit). ... OK, I just checked and for undeclared variables it says "Identifier is not recognized" when you try to go to the definition.

Comment: @RBarryYoung, added in the OP the image with my try to navigate to definition of an undeclared variable (error)

Comment: @serge thank you for this query, it really helped me to learn something new!

Comment: @freeflow, once again, there is not the question to find "infidelities", but to understand what the existing code does.